# iOS Wifi-Direct Communication

Tags: ios, gamekit, wifi-direct, multipeer-connectivity

I'm wondering if there's a way for two iPhones to communicate with Wifi-Direct Exclusively.

(No Bluetooth, No Servers, Just Wifi-Direct)

Correct me if I'm wrong, but MultiPeerConnectivity, GameKit, and CFNetServices don't allow using exclusively Wifi-Direct. If they do can someone show me an example?

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Multipeer Connectivity framework does not support Wi-Fi Direct but it *does* support direct ad-hoc connections between two iOS devices using a proprietary Apple technology that's similar to Wi-Fi Direct.

It's mentioned on the [Multipeer reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MultipeerConnectivity/Reference/MultipeerConnectivityFramework/Introduction/Introduction.html) where it's called "peer-to-peer Wi-Fi".

You can also get more basic peer-to-peer Wi-Fi discovery and communication between two iOS devices using Bonjour with `NSNetService` and `NSNetServiceBrowser`, if you set the `includesPeerToPeer` property to YES on each (Note this is not mentioned in the online docs but it is in the header files). This is what Multipeer Connectivity is built on.

Comment: Could you point me in the right direction for learning how to do this?

Comment: Basically, try any MultiPeer Connectivity tutorial, like [this one](http://www.appcoda.com/intro-multipeer-connectivity-framework-ios-programming/), and when you test it, use two physical iDevices that both have Wi-Fi enabled, Bluetooth disabled, and are not connected to any existing Wi-Fi network. After some time, you should find that they can discover each other and connect. No special code is needed to setup the peer-to-peer Wi-Fi beyond the "normal" Multipeer Connectivity code. (Using NSNetService is optional and more complex, so don't start with that.)

Comment: Is there a way for this process to not use bluetooth but still have bluetooth enabled?

Comment: I don't think the API provides a way for you to control whether it uses Wi-Fi or Bluetooth, if both are enabled. The Multipeer framework will use whichever it thinks "best." It may in fact prefer Wi-Fi over Bluetooth but I haven't tested it.

Comment: In short I need two iDevices talking to eachother over wifi-direct only. I still need Bluetooth enabled. They both have to be connected to the internet.

Comment: What's your reason for worrying about which technology is used? The Multipeer framework is designed to (in theory) provide the same experience regardless of whether it's using Wi-Fi or Bluetooth.

Comment: I have another device connected by bluetooth. It's pushing that to it's limits. So it would be ideal to have the iDevices talking to each other through a different medium. Wifi-Direct seems to be my best option.

Comment: @bradenm : So are you saying that Multipeer Connectivity framework doesn't support Wifi-Direct? Because I'm working on a problem where I need to connect iPhone with non-iOS device through Wifi-Direct. Do you have any solution for my problem.?

Comment: @DGoogly Yes, that's what I'm saying; it only supports iOS-to-iOS over Wi-Fi using a proprietary protocol. That was true at the time I wrote this answer; I don't know if the situation has changed since then.